# PayPal is accepting payments with no found cards

Tags: paypal, pending-transition

I just integrated REST API apps, but I tested to make a purchase, my debit card had no funds. Still that, Paypal redirect to me to the thank you Page. Also, the report of this transaction not appear in my dashboard. My developer says that there is no settings for that.

I don't see the transaction in my dashboard, so is not marked like failed or pending or something. I'm sure there is a bug in the code. I'm using Express Checkout / Payments REST API. Apparently the problem is: my integration is not detecting correctly the calls and PayPal is not processing the payments. I also, don't received any email from PayPal about that transaction.

Which part of the integration could be wrong? Because I need to tell my developer to fix it.

Comment: What sort of card was it - debit, credit, etc? Can you examine the transaction in a PayPal dashboard to see if it was regarded as valid? If it is marked as failed but you still got a thank you then you have a bug in the code on your side. Unfortunately there is insufficient information here for readers to be able to help - I doubt anyone can help on such minimal information. Therefore, would you expand on the question by adding any relevant information? What PayPal product are you using?

Comment: it was a debit card. I don't see the transaction in my dashboard, so is not marked like failed or pending or something. I'm sure there is a bug in the code.  I'm using Express Checkout / Payments REST API. Yeah, sadly for me, I don't have too much information. 
Apparently the problem is: my integration is not detecting correctly the calls and pay pal is not processing the payments. I also, don't received any email from paypal about that transaction.
I'm not really sure if there is a problem with the code or any other configuration from my side (dashboard)

Comment: Are you checking the right dashboard? Maybe the transaction has gone to a staging or live dashboard, and you're looking at the other?

Comment: I checked in https://www.paypal.com/businessexp/transactions
How many dashboards I have. I'm sorry I don't even know it. I'm searching some documentation, but it's infinite.

Comment: I don't know how many dashboards you have - the point is that your dev may be using a different account for a staging system.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Yeah, because I have 4 sandbox accounts right now. And everything is really confusing.

Comment: Your developer, if they are any good, should be communicating this all to you. I assume that he/she has tested this basic operation before releasing it to you.